# Limiting marketing cloud reports data to one business unit only

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, query, data-export

By looking at the data of several marketing cloud default reports in our business only, it looks like the data is being pulled in the reports from all business units (top level) account not just our business unit.

Is there any way to limit the data to one business unit only?

I even tried running a few queries on data view but that data is also for whole top level account, not just one business unit.

Comment: Have you tried editing the report and adding a filter for just one unit? It sounds like your org's are open so you see them all.

Comment: There is no option in default reports to add business unit filter.

Answer (score 0):

Run the report from inside the business unit you want the report from.